# Sort list of date strings

Tags: python, datetime

I have an arbitrary list of date strings (mm-yyyy) as follows:

```
d = ['09-2012', '04-2007', '11-2012', '05-2013', '12-2006', '05-2006', '08-2007'...]
```

I need this list to be sorted first by the level of years (ascending), then on the level of months (ascending)..so that the logical ordering can be:

```
d_ordered = ['05-2006', '12-2006', '04-2007', '08-2007', '09-2012', '11-2012', '05-2013' ...]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Quick and dirty: `d.sort(key=lambda x: x.split('-')[::-1])`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
d = ['09-2012', '04-2007', '11-2012', '05-2013', '12-2006', '05-2006', '08-2007']
sorted(d, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%Y'))
```

Comment: Use reverse= True for decreasing order

`sorted(d, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%Y'), reverse=True)`

Comment: Hello matellanes and thanks for the previous answers. I'm reying to do the same to dates in string format day-month-year but to no avail. If it's not too much to ask (I'm basically using python to prototype mobile servers (and learn something new). *** result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(result, '%Y-%M-%D'))***

Comment: If its day-month-year, e.g. 12-04-2023, try `%d-%m-%Y` rather than `%Y-%M-%D`.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a key:

```
>>> d = ['09-2012', '04-2007', '11-2012', '05-2013', '12-2006', '05-2006', '08-2007']
>>> def sorting(L):
...     splitup = L.split('-')
...     return splitup[1], splitup[0]
... 
>>> sorted(d, key=sorting)
['05-2006', '12-2006', '04-2007', '08-2007', '09-2012', '11-2012', '05-2013']
```

It's better to use a function here instead of a lambda to prevent calling `split()` twice (and it looks a bit neater :))

Note that this will return the sorted list. If you want to sort it in place, use `.sort()`:

```
>>> d.sort(key=sorting)
>>> d
['05-2006', '12-2006', '04-2007', '08-2007', '09-2012', '11-2012', '05-2013']
```