# Sort a List containing date and time string elements

Tags: python, list

I need assistance in sorting a list by date and time, both date and time are string fields within my list.

```
myList = ['item1', 'item2', 'mm/dd/yy', 'hh:mmAM', 'item3']
```

I'm using Python 2.4.3.

I'm using the Bob Swift CLI to pull page info from Atlassian's Confluence and place into a list so it can then be sorted to showing the oldest pages first.

Sample Data:

pageList = "['Page Title', '383551192', '298288254', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16 1:05 PM', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16', '1:16PM', '2', 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8xxx/display/mine/PageTitle']"

I need to sort on the last modified date at element 6 and time at 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort list of date strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627531/sort-list-of-date-strings)

Comment: `item1` doesn't look like a date or time... how do you want that sorted?

Comment: It appears from your `myList` that you probably have a list of lists. Python sort is stable. Sort twice, first by time then by date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your data in a list of list which I think you probably do. I changed pageList to do this with each inner list having a different time. Now we can use python's sort() but we have to provide our own compare function. So here we have pageList.sort(mySort) The sort() passes two list items for comparison. Here each item is an inner list. We need to combine elements 6 and 7 to form a single date time string; then convert this to a python datetime so we can compare them.

Since the tuples are long I only print out the date and time values from the inner list after the sort to show it works.

```
import datetime

pageList =[['Page Title', '383551192', '298288254', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16 1:05 PM', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16', '1:56PM', '2', 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8xxx/display/mine/PageTitle'],
           ['Page Title', '383551192', '298288254', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16 1:05 PM', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16', '1:46PM', '2', 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8xxx/display/mine/PageTitle'],
           ['Page Title', '383551192', '298288254', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16 1:05 PM', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16', '1:56PM', '2', 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8xxx/display/mine/PageTitle'],
           ['Page Title', '383551192', '298288254', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16 1:05 PM', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16', '1:16PM', '2', 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8xxx/display/mine/PageTitle'],
           ['Page Title', '383551192', '298288254', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16 1:05 PM', 'dt206xxx', '1/7/16', '1:36PM', '2', 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8xxx/display/mine/PageTitle']]

def mySort(a,b):
    c = a[6] + ' ' + a[7]
    d = b[6] + ' ' + b[7]
    date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(c, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
    return cmp(date1, date2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pageList.sort(mySort)
    for i in range(len(pageList)):
        print i,pageList[i][6],' ',pageList[i][7]
```

Output:
0 1/7/16   1:16PM
1 1/7/16   1:36PM
2 1/7/16   1:46PM
3 1/7/16   1:56PM
4 1/7/16   1:56PM

Comment: Receiving the following error, guessing its due to run an old version of Python, 2.4.3.

Comment: date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(c, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p')
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: format = '%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p'
date1 = time.strptime(c, format)[0:6]
date2 = time.strptime(d, format)[0:6]