# python datetime incorrect sorted

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter

I'm getting some database dates and they can get mixed up.
I use the sorted () method to print these dates on a regular basis

```
datelist = ["1 2017", "2 2017", "6 2017",  "7 2017", "8 2017", "3 2017", "4 2017", "5 2017", "9 2017", "10 2017", "11 2017", "12 2017"]

for i in sorted(datelist):
        print(i)
```

But the result is terrible ..!

```
1 2017
10 2017
11 2017
12 2017
2 2017
3 2017
4 2017
5 2017
6 2017
7 2017
8 2017
9 2017
```

How can I get these values ​​regularly?
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: They're not datetimes. They're strings. So they're being sorted like strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627531/sort-list-of-date-strings

Comment: I'm saving these dates to the database with spinbox. This could be str. I am using Tkinter and I have not found another way to select and save the date. Again, Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` parameter of `sorted` to parse the string and sort by a `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
datelist = ["1 2017", "2 2017", "6 2017",  "7 2017", "8 2017", "3 2017", "4 2017", "5 2017", "9 2017", "10 2017", "11 2017", "12 2017"]
for i in sorted(datelist,key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s,'%m %Y')):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1 2017
2 2017
3 2017
4 2017
5 2017
6 2017
7 2017
8 2017
9 2017
10 2017
11 2017
12 2017
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: yes, this be better when i add "1 2018", "2 2018" too :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are performing sort on the string values and the sorting on strings are done [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). In order to sort the strings in your list in the numeric ascending order, you may pass `key` argument as a *lambda* function with the `sorted` as:

```
>>> datelist = ["1 2017", "2 2017", "6 2017",  "7 2017", "8 2017", "3 2017", "4 2017", "5 2017", "9 2017", "10 2017", "11 2017", "12 2017"]

>>> sorted(datelist, key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split()])
['1 2017', '2 2017', '3 2017', '4 2017', '5 2017', '6 2017', '7 2017', '8 2017', '9 2017', '10 2017', '11 2017', '12 2017']
```