# Sorting a list of strings based on the first element from split (datetime)

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime, partition

I have a long list of strings, separated by commas (basically, csv files read line by line to strings, not performing a split on the separator):

```py
lines[0] = "2017-08-01 13:45:58,mytext,mytext2,mytext3,etc"
lines[1] = "2017-08-01 15:45:58,mytextx,mytext2x,mytext3x,etcx"
lines[2] = "2017-08-01 19:45:58,mytexty,mytext2y,mytext3y,etcy"
lines[3] = "..."
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627531/sort-list-of-date-strings) post I know that the following code should work if my lines would only consist of datetimes:

```py
lines_sorted = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(lines, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I thought I could use `partition` to extract tuples from all lines in files, where the first element contains the datetimepart:

```py
for unsortedFile in glob('*.txt'):
    with open(unsortedFile, 'r') as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n').partition(',') for line in file]
        lines_sorted = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(lines[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

..but of course, this does not work "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" because `lines[0]` is not referencing the first tuple but the first item in lines-list. I also tried using `.strptime(lines[lambda][0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` but it is neither working.

I know I am doing something wrong.. any help is much appreciated.

[edit]
Here's the answer, from friendly comments below:

```py
for unsortedFile in glob('*.txt'):
    with open(unsortedFile, 'r', encoding="utf8") as file: #read each unsorted file to lines (list)
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
        lines_sorted = sorted(lines,
                    key=lambda x: x.split(',', maxsplit=1)[0]
                    )
        lines.clear()
    with open(unsortedFile,'w', encoding="utf8") as file: #overwrite file
        for line in lines_sorted:
            file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Replace `lines[0]` with `x[0]`.

Comment: should be `x.split(',')[0]` (or `x.partition(',')[0]`)

Comment: Given the format of your strings and dates, you don't really need to convert to `datetime` objects to sort them; regular string ordering will give you the same result, so you can drop the `key` parameter in `sort`.

Comment: Thank you guys, all comments were very useful! I will update the post

Comment: Also [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) will give you tuples like `("2017-08-01 13:45:58", ",", "mytext,mytext2,mytext3,etc")`; you sure you don't want [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with `maxsplit=1` (which would give you `("2017-08-01 13:45:58", "mytext,mytext2,mytext3,etc")`)?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, I will update the original post in a few Minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically the `key` argument of the `sorted` function must be a function which takes a list item and returns a comparable object.
`sorted` will sort the list according to the image of the list items by this function, not the items themselves.

Here is an example, which is a mix of the suggested solutions :

```
lines_sorted = sorted(lines,
                      key=lambda x: x.split(',', maxsplit=1)[0]
                     )
```

With this code, every item which has the same date will be considered equal by `sorted`.

Comment: Thank you, User9123, this really looks like the fasted approach (without datetimeconversion and using maxsplit=1 instead of partition. I added yours as the right answer, although everyone that commented contributed - thanks to all for the great help!

Answer (score 2):

Just take the first element of the `split`:

```
lines_sorted = sorted(
    lines, 
    key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.split(",")[0], 
                                            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
))
```

This way you are just taking the datetime for the sorting while keeping the original data.